# ActionBarDrawerToggle что использовать: int drawerImageRes или toolbar?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-toolbar, android-navigation-drawer

Почему в официальном примере в конструкторе `ActionBarDrawerToggle` вставляется `toolbar` а не как в документации `int drawerImageRes`

http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё дело в том, что вы смотрите на доки устаревшей версии класса. Там так и написано:

> This class is deprecated.
>
> Please use ActionBarDrawerToggle in support-v7-appcompat.

В примерах (если они учитывают это, а вами рассмотренный как раз из таких) используется как раз таки новая [реализация](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html)